# How to remove timezone value after retrieving data from cloud firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to get the date and time without timezone? I am utilizing `toDate()` and am ending up with output including date, time and timezone. How do I remove the timezone?

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(MessagesHolder holder, int position,  Messages model) {
        holder.textViewMessages.setText(model.getMessages());
        holder.textViewUser.setText(model.getUser());
        holder.timeStamp.setText(model.getTimePosted().toDate().toString());
}
```

Below are the screenshot of my cloud firestore.
[image: Cloud Firestore Database]

Below are the screenshop of my apps.
[image: Screenshot of my app]

Answer (score 2):

According to the API documentation for [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp):

> A Timestamp represents a point in time **independent of any time zone or
>   calendar**, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
>   nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

What you are seeing is not a timezone encoded into the timestamp.  What you're seeing is an interpretation of that timestamp using the clock of the local device.  That's always what calling toString on a date object will do, and that string is generally not meant for display in an app.

If you want to format the timestamp for another timezone, you will need to use a library to format that date in the timezone you choose, such as Joda Time, or one of the Android APIs for formatting dates and times.

Comment: I created SimpleDateFormat with pattern (MMMM dd yyyy, hh:mm a) solved my problem